# SQLCBLLE not running correctly and does not produce MSGW

Tags: debugging, batch-processing, ibm-midrange

I have been facing this problem lately :

normaly when there is a pgm ILE COBOL running on batch job on IBM i-series (AS/400) and triggers an exeption it makes the batch job stop et go from RUN to MSGW, but when it is a SQLCBLLE and there is a problem executing an sql statement it simply rolls back and continues execution without passing the job to MSGW.

Is there a way to know if an sqlcblle in a batch job has not executed correctly and if there is a possibility to trigger MSGW for the batch job and let the default error handler get them ?

Comment: `"Is there a way to know..."` Yes, the ways to know depend on how you code the program, but also what the problems are. Unless we know the kinds of problems you're asking about and what the related code looks like, there are far too many possibilities.

Comment: My problem is that must of the time i am not authorised to edit the pgms and recompile ! While running an sqlcblle pgm in batch ( sbmjob ) the batch job executes normally and leaves no log so ever saying that it didnt run as supposed even if the sql queries inside the pgm were returning errors the job just skips the rest of the code ! But when the pgm is in cobol the job turns from status run to msgw waiting for user response ! I need to have the same behavior for sqlcblle pgm ! Actually the method i am using is to check time execution to valide batch run if an sqlcblle takes normally 30 min a

Comment: one day it would take 2-3min. It's not a reliable way ! What is the correct way ?

Comment: `What is the correct way ?`  To do what? We have no idea what a correct way might be without seeing the code that isn't working as desired. There are too many "correct ways" that are different from each other in different code. We don't even know what errors are involved nor how they arise.

Comment: Every error resulting in any sql statement. In a more clear way if i have an sqlcblle pgm with the source : exec sql select * from tableA and i dont have no tableA in my database i run the pgm in batch job the job runs and finishes leaving no error !

Comment: That's right, nor should there be any exception from that in SQL. The exception message model is how the AS/400-series of systems signals problems, but SQL is a kind of platform-neutral facility. Since SQL doesn't generate exception messages, there usually is no useful way to monitor for them (unless they're from failures of the SQL engine itself). If you use SQL, you have to use SQL error handling. Put IF-tests in the code after each `EXEC SQL` block to check the value of SQLSTATE. You might be able to use the 'EXEC SQL  WHENEVER SQLERROR GO TO ...   END-EXEC' construct also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every SQL statement should be followed by a test that checks SQLSTATE (or possibly SQLCODE) to see if the SQL succeeded. Depending on the SQLSTATE (or perhaps SQLCODE) value, the program needs to decide what action to take.

The action can be to send a *INQ message to put the job into MSGW status until a reply is returned.

Without seeing code that causes a problem, it's difficult to say much more. A statement such as `exec sql select * from tableA` already has a potentially significant problem by not specifying a column list, regardless of the existence of `tableA`. Embedded SQL generally will not cause an exception to be returned, but will use SQLSTATE to describe problems. It's the developer's responsibility to check for those returned conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no way using CL commands to check on sqlcblle logs ? Can you post some link to reference handling SQLSTATE inside the pgm ?

Comment: You can use CL to check on SQL results _if the program makes results available_. If the developer has simply discarded SQL problems, then the problem info is gone. The [*SQL messages and codes*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzala/rzalakickoff.htm?lang=en) topic in the Information Center has everything there is to know about return signals from SQL. The [*Embedded SQL programming*](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzajp/rzajpkickoff.htm?lang=en) topic has coding examples in multiple programming languages.

Comment: Note that it isn't just "SQL" programs. Many developers ignore error indications whether they come from SQL or not. It's the same problem; just different coding.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting discussion that may be helpful [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d2c49b79-5a01-46f7-9a11-b9de0f2b0e02). It's about RPG rather than CBL but may be useful in solving your problem.